# How to auto run hide-ifdef-mode's hide-ifdefs command

Tags: syntax-highlighting, c-mode

I've been using `hide-ifdef-mode` with `c-mode` buffers for a while, but it is quite tedious to have to manually run `hide-ifdefs` (`C-c @ h`) every time a block of code containing preprocessors changes.

Is there any way this can be run automatically? (for example during syntax highlighting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I think I have found a viable solution:  add `hide-ifdefs` to `after-save-hook` hook when running `c-mode-common-hook` - like so:

```lisp
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
             (lambda ()
               (hide-ifdef-mode)
               ;... your other hook code here
               (add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (hide-ifdefs)))
               )
```

The sequence is: open a C file which runs the `c-mode-common-hook`; that enables `hide-ifdef-mode` and adds a function to the buffer's `after-save-hook`. Eventually, when the buffer is saved, the `after-save-hook` is run which executes `hide-ifdefs`.